# Is there a way to display an 'All' link following the alphabetic glossary with Views 7.x-3.x?

Tags: views, paging

I have an existing feature in a Drupal 5 site I'm trying to reproduce in Views 7x3x, but I didn't find a way to make it happen.

I have the glossary functionality working in Views 7.x-3.x but the 'All' link functionality is eluding me. This selector needs to work in combination with a filter (taxonomy) so this limits the obvious workarounds because the Views module needs to be aware of the filtering.

How do I display an 'All' link following the alphabetic glossary?

[image: views glossary "All" link]

I have it working using a jQuery snippet, but would love an elegant server side solution.

---

I found these [solutions](http://drupal.org/node/403012) on drupal.org.

I haven't tested any but if anyone does; please post your experience as an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering views-views-summary-unformatted.tpl.php is certainly the way forward. Don't be lazy and use the header if you can't get the template file to register initially, it's worth it in the end. That way you can add --view_name on the end and target all displays without having to copy bits of code around, or symlink the file to target another view or specific display so that you don't have to edit twice.

As I mention in [the post](http://drupal.org/node/403012) we both linked to, the HTML doesn't validate if you use any exposed filters but it's fixable with regex.

The post has recently been updated; there is a version for 7 that includes 0-9 and ALL which works as described, if that answers your question?

Additionally you refer to the glossary as a filter but it is actually an argument selector. On my site I have it working with two taxonomy filters.

Comment: Thanks griz for pointing out the glossary is a selector and not a filter; i'll edit my question for clarity/correctness.